# Extracting javascript using Web::Scraper

Tags: javascript, html, perl, parsing

I'm having trouble extracting javascript using Web::Scraper.  Below is my test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use Web::Scraper;
use Data::Dumper;

my $contents = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $scraper = scraper { process "//script", "scripts[]" => 'TEXT'; };
my $res = $scraper->scrape($contents);

say Dumper $res;

exit;

__DATA__
<html><head><title>hello</title></head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dummy = {}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'scripts' => [
                         ''
                       ]
        };
```

It seems to me that I'm finding the script tag but not saving the contents between the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after digging into xpath a bit.

Changing the scraper line from:

```
my $scraper = scraper { process "//script", "scripts[]" => 'TEXT'; };
```

To:

```
my $scraper = scraper { process "//script" => 'scripts[]' =>
                    scraper { process '//text()', 'script'=>'TEXT'} };
```

Outputs the javascript code:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'scripts' => [
                         {
                           'script' => '
    var dummy = {}
  '
                         }
                       ]
        };
```

I'm not convinced the process line is concise but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try RAW like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict;
use warnings;
use Web::Scraper;
use Data::Dump;
my $contents = q{
<html><head><title>hello</title></head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dummy = {}
  </script>
</body>
</html>};
#~ my $scraper = scraper { process "//script", "scripts[]" => 'TEXT'; };
my $scraper = scraper { process "//script", "scripts[]" => 'RAW'; };
my $res = $scraper->scrape($contents);
dd $res;
__END__
{ scripts => ["\n    var dummy = {}"] }
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  I tried the change and it does pull out the js code.  The only problem is that the data in the var has quotes which renders as `&quot;` which makes parsing the data harder.